# Android Studio - how to remove white space above layout

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, screen-size

I am trying to create an Android app with basic textViews, textEdits and Buttons. For some reason, a blank white space appears above the layout. This does not happen in the XML design view but does happen on the Nexus 5, Nexus 5X and the 5.4 FWVGA emulators and on my actual phone (a Huawei P Smart).

I have only just started with Android Studio and do not fully understand layouts, etc... I have tried changing the layout to a relative layout, but it is still there. Also, suggested fixes on Google DIDN'T work.

My activity_main.xml:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@drawable/bg_colour_gradient"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pi_user"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.EditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Pi's SSH Username"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pi_pass"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.904" />
```

A screenshot of the app messed up in the emulator, and the design view:

[image: App messed up in emulator]

Comment: Can you provide the code of your `styles.xml` file?

Comment: Yes. I am not by the computer right now. Should be able the get

Comment: to get the file posted in 15 mins

Comment: OMG yes! @Valentin's answer was right, but until you prompted me to look in the file, I wouldn't have found out that Android Studio wasn't changing it for me! Before it was like this: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">, now it I changed it manually, it is like this <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: That's why I asked for the `styles.xml` file. :)

Comment: Yep, thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make theme in xml file from yours to AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

[image]

Or you can try to do it manual in `styles.xml` file :

from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Thanks, will try when I get back to my computer. 

Comment: just changing the dropdown didn't work for me, however, if you look in the styles.xml file (as suggested by @ankuranurag2) and change it manually, it works! Can you edit your post to include this, then I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for getting me out of this mess again! Really appreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was problem in my manifest file as "theme" wasn't defined for the activity there

```
  <activity    
        android:name=".activity.NotificationActivity">
    </activity>
```

I just added the theme manually like this and it fixed my problem

```
   <activity
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:name=".activity.NotificationActivity">
    </activity>
```

So make sure to check the manifest also